# Swiftui center hstack in vstack

Tags: swiftui

I have simple Hstack in Zstack but issue is Its to showing in centre I have added a padding which is showing on right side not in left because its not in centre.

My code

```
            ZStack (alignment: .center){
                
                HStack (alignment: .center) {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height/12)
                .background(Color("primarycolor").shadow(radius: 2))
                
            }.padding()
```

Here is preview

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is with the simple math. so that I have extracted the padding variable out.

Note: `Geometry` reader gets space as much as possible and we access with the given proxy.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        var padding: CGFloat = 10
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack (alignment: .center){
                
                HStack (alignment: .center) {
                    
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width - (padding * 2), height: geometry.size.height/12)
                .background(Color.red.shadow(radius: 2))
                .border(.gray, width: 5)
                
            }
            .padding(padding)
            .border(.gray, width: 5)
        }
    }
}
```